# How to use NPOI to get user defined format from a cell in xlsx file?

Tags: xlsx, npoi

Background: I have a Date cell with the following user defined format `ggge"年"m"月"d"日"`. However, if I call `cell.CellType` on this cell, the return value would be `Numeric`.

I need to distinguish it from other Numeric cells, but `DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)` returns `false` in this case (I believe it is because this is not a built-in Date format).

So I'm thinking if I can get the format of each cell, I can use it to determine if a cell is a Date cell or not. However, `cell.CellStyle.DataFormat` would only return a number code. Is there any way to get the format `ggge"年"m"月"d"日` from NPOI's ICell object?